# ¿Solve Delayed Logistic Equation or Hutchinson's Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I would like to know the analytical solution of the following ODE.

**[Hutchinson's Equation]**

$N'(t)=rN(t)(1-\frac{N(t-\tau)}{K})$

Where $r> 0$ is the intrinsic growth rate of the species and $K> 0$ is the persistence capacity or carrying capacity for said species.

This formula comes from the Verhulst logistic equation whose form is.

**[Verhulst Logistic Equation]**

$N'(t)=rN(t)(1-\frac{N(t)}{K})$

Only that Hutchinson's equation considers tau "$\tau$" as the retarder (delay or lag)

***What would be the solution of the Hutchinson's equation?***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If that equation has a name, and you search for it, and no solutions turn up, then it's reasonable to suspect...

Comment: I looked for a lot of information about their solution, and there isn't much information about an "analytical solution", but I have seen a "characteristic equation" of it, but I don't know how they get to it.

Comment: I cannot catch what does the word 'analytic solution' actually mean. Do you want to know how to solve it as a logistic equation?

Comment: When I refer to "analytical solution" when the solution is expressed as a function of N (t) (http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/first/analytic/analytic.html)